# solving polynomial equation (showing non-negativity)

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients, systems-of-equations, alternative-proof

I would like to show that for all $a,b\geq 0$, and integer $k\geq 1$, we have $(a+b)^k\leq 2^k(a^k+b^k)$. Is there an elegant way to prove this other than induction?

Thanks

Comment: The [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Special_cases) gives the stronger:$$\;\dfrac{a+b}{2} \le \sqrt[k]{\dfrac{a^k+b^k}{2}} \;\;\iff\;\; (a+b)^k \le 2^{\color{red}{k-1}}(a^k+b^k)\,$$

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent as
$$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^k\leq a^k+b^k$$
Which is clearly true since $f(x)=x^k$ is strictly increasing, and
$$\min(a,b)\leq \frac{a+b}{2}\leq\max(a,b).$$

To explain further, suppose $a\leq b$, then because $f$ is increasing you have
$$f(a)\leq f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\leq f(b) \leq f(a)+f(b).$$

Thus it even holds if you replace the rhs of your original inequality by $2^k\max(a^k,b^k)$.

Comment: $x^{1/2}$ is increasing and the property that you want doesn't hold for it.

Comment: Well $k$ is an integer $\geq 1$

Comment: It is not increasing what gives you the property you want, it is convexity.

Comment: Not sure of that, since $f((a+b)/2)<f(\max(a,b))$ is ensured by increasing only and implies the OP inequality. Are you sure?

Comment: $\sqrt{(a+b)/2}\leq \sqrt b$ for $a/leq b$ and therefore the inequality holds for $k=1/2$ actually...

Comment: @YAlexandrov for $a<b$ exists $c>0$ such that $(a+b)/2=(b-c+b)/2=b-c/2<b$ hence, by the definition of monotonic increasing function we have $f((a+b)/2)<f(b)$, if we define strictly increasing as non-decreasing we have $f((a+b)/2)\le f(b)$

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to prove this inequality

Answer (score -1):

Note that
$$
a+b\leq2\max(a,b)\implies(a+b)^k\leq2^k(\max(a,b))^k=2^k(\max(a^k,b^k))\leq2^k(a^k+b^k).
$$
where we used $x^k$ is strictly increasing for $x\ge 0$.